# My @media statement is not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I used this code to make my website responsive, but it isn't working. The @media screen part is black and it seems like my browser doesn't recognize this code.

```
@media screen and(max-width: 478px) {
 body {
  font-size: 13px;
 }
}
@media screen and(max-width: 740px) {
 nav{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
 nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #878E63
 }
 nav ul li a{
    padding: 8px 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
 }
 .left-col{
    width: 100%;
 }
 .sidebar{
    width: 100%;
 }
 .section{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not problem of those tags you tagged in your question. Just tag nodepad++, though you won't get answer... you need to contact its vendor...

Comment: This is probably something you'll need to contact the vendor about.

Comment: Try using a different editor like sublime text.

Comment: the looks aren't the problem. The problem is that this code isn't working and my site isn't responsive.

Comment: Then what has your text editor to do with it?

Comment: I just mentioned what text editor I use.

Comment: No, you said "Notepad++ doesn't recognize this code". Please amend your question and include only relevant information.

Comment: omg! I said it, the code isn't working properly. I'm trying to make my website responsive and It doesn't work.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't run nor care about your code. It's completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: can then someone give me a advice how to make this code to work?

Comment: Removed references to Notepad++ which sparked most of the above comments.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle example which reproduces the issue. Your CSS looks fine to me. We would need to see your HTML.

Comment: It's always good to check the code with a [CSS Linter](http://csslint.net/), for correct syntax.

Comment: Add a space between `and` and `(max-width...` like `and (max-width: 740px)` instead of `and(max-width: 740px)`

Comment: @pbaldauf your answer helped! tnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the initial scale of your page?:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```